# Prototype property of functions

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, function-prototypes

When I try to access the Prototype property of functions it gives me the following result:

```
console.log(Function.prototype); //  () { [native code] }
```

But when I perform the same operation on other objects like `Arrays` it shows me the actual prototype of Array where all the methods are linked

```
console.log(Array.prototype); //  [constructor: ƒ, concat: ƒ, copyWithin: ƒ, fill: ƒ, find: ƒ, …]
```

What I really want to know is why the `Functions` behave differently.

Comment: Where do you see this output? `console.log(Function.prototype);` [shows me this](https://i.imgur.com/k4EdbfG.png) in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging functions with `console.log` will log the text of the function. If the function is not written in JavaScript - for example, like here, if the implementation is provided by the environment - it'll give you `[native code]` instead.

But there's an easy way to log at the properties on the function, at least in Chrome: use `console.dir`.

```js
console.dir(Function.prototype)
```

```html
<img src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GEij.png">
```

which gives you the function properties as expected, at least in both Chrome and FF.

The functionality of this `Function.prototype` is described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object).